How to initate firebase command globally?
I have installed firebase CLI using the firebase website , (not the npm/node.js one) I have setup everything , now the problem is that firebase command only works in firebase CLI and not in cmd or vscode terminal. I cant find where the firebase exe is so that I could put it in my path variable , but I have installed firebase , since when i run this command
firebase --version in firebase CLI I get 13.15.1 , any help ?
tried firebase --version in firebase CLI , got 13.15.1 , but it doesn't work in cmd or vscode terminal

Check in Windows task manager the location of the CLI process.
